# @Transactional annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Hi I'm learning Spring Framework after my Java Core Study. I'm making very simple CRUD MVC application. There is a problem @Transactional annotation doesn't work. Could someone more expierienced in that matter help me? Stack:(Java,Spring,Hibernate,Maven).

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.adrianzaplata</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>hibernate-tutorial Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>hibernate-tutorial</finalName>
  <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

my configuration:

```
package com.adrianzaplata.project.config;


import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.adrianzaplata.project"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?useSSL=false");
        cpds.setUser("adrian");
        cpds.setPassword("chomik12");

        cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        cpds.setMaxIdleTime(30000);

        return cpds;
    }
//
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean beanFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(comboPooledDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.adrianzaplata.project.entities");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return factory;

    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(beanFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }






}
```

my init class instead of web.xml

```
package com.adrianzaplata.project.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        Class[] confClasses = {AppConfig.class};
        return confClasses;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        String[] mappings = {"/"};
        return mappings;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.adrianzaplata.project.controllers;


import com.adrianzaplata.project.entities.Customer;
import com.adrianzaplata.project.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String listCustomers(Model model)
    {
       List<Customer> theCustomers = customerService.getAllCustomers();
       model.addAttribute("customers",theCustomers);
        return "customer-all";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showAddForm")
    public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("CustomerDTO") Customer customerDTO)
    {
        return "add-customer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/process-add-form")
    public void processCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("CustomerDTO") Customer customerDTO) throws IOException {
        customerService.addCustomer(customerDTO);

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/customer/all");
    }




}

At the moment I'm able to read customers from database but method addCustomer doesn't work unless managed transcaction manually inside saveCustomer() method. I suspect that reading customers also does not work by @Transactional annotation.
```

Service

```
package com.adrianzaplata.project.service;

import com.adrianzaplata.project.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.adrianzaplata.project.entities.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers()
    {
        return customerDao.getCustomers();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerDao.addCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

DAO

```
package com.adrianzaplata.project.dao;

import com.adrianzaplata.project.entities.Customer;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * from customer");
            query.addEntity(Customer.class);
            List<Customer> customers = query.list();
            return customers;

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(customer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "@Transactional annotation doesn't work"?

Comment: @Transactional doesn't impact on my application. I have to manage my hibernate transactions manually.

Comment: @Transactional means that the code inside of the method will either be executed all at once or in case of a (by default runtime) exceptoion all of the method code will be rolled back. Since you only have one line in your transactional method what exactly do you expect to be different?  Here is an example: https://javamondays.com/spring-transactions-explained/

Comment: Try separating your hibernate config from web configs and return from `getRootConfigs` and remove `@Configuration` annotation from `AppInit` class, it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to use @Transactional to help me reduce boilerplate code i have to use for hibernate but when i use @Transactional my logic from dao class does not execute. (No queries to database).

Comment: If you want to reduce boilerplate code, I highly recommend using Spring Boot instead of plain Spring. It will configure datasource, transaction manager, and all that kind of stuff for you. Also Spring Data will provide generic DAOs for you, no need to use Session or SessionFactory, no need to implement findAll, save, update, delete methods, etc.